# Typescript Filter Array By Another Array

Tags: typescript

I need to filter one array of objects, by another array of objects.  How do I do that with Typescript?

The below TS works except for the last line.

Goal: To get all vendors who service countyId = 1.

A Vendor can service more than one county.

There are three vendors, #1 in one county, #2 in two counties.

```js
var all_vendors = [{ id: 1, name: 'A' }, { id: 2, name : 'B'}, { id: 3, name : 'c'}];
console.log('all vendors');
console.log(all_vendors);
var all_vendor_counties = [{ id: 1, vendorId: 1, countyId: 1 }, { id: 2, vendorId: 2, countyId: 1 }, { id: 3, vendorId: 2, countyId: 2 },];
console.log('All Vendor Counties')
console.log(all_vendor_counties);
var filtered_vendor_counties = all_vendor_counties.filter(a => a.countyId === 1);//return two vendor_counties.
console.log('Filtered Vendor Counties')
console.log(filtered_vendor_counties); 
//??? var allVendorsInCounty1 = all_vendors.filter( a=> //a is in filtered_vendor_counties)
```

Comment: you mean like [...all_vendors ,...all_vendor_counties].filter(...) ?

Comment: @jonathanHeindl, I am sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: @jonathan that would treat them as the same kind of object, rather than filter vendors to `allVendorsInCounty1`

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question in javascript this would be best to do with switch map but I tihnk in typescript you first filter the all_vendor_counties array , then map each county to an arrays of existing vendors ,  and then reduce them all into the same array

Comment: all_vendor_counties .filter(a => a.countyId === 1) .map(county=>all_vendors.filter(vendor=>vendor.id==county.id)).reduce((arr,next)=>[...arr,...next],[])

Comment: I hope I didnt miss anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First iterate over `all_vendor_counties` to create a Set containing all `vendorId`s you want to filter by, then `filter` the `all_vendors` array by whether the vendor's `id` is included in that Set:

```js
var all_vendors = [{ id: 1, name: 'A' }, { id: 2, name : 'B'}, { id: 3, name : 'c'}];
var all_vendor_counties = [{ id: 1, vendorId: 1, countyId: 1 }, { id: 2, vendorId: 2, countyId: 1 }, { id: 3, vendorId: 2, countyId: 2 },];

const vendorIds = new Set(all_vendor_counties
  .filter(({ countyId }) => countyId === 1)
  .map(({ vendorId }) => vendorId)
);
const vendorsInCountyIds = all_vendors.filter(({ id }) => vendorIds.has(id));

console.log(vendorsInCountyIds);
```

(could also use an array and use `.includes` instead of the Set's `.has`, but `.includes` has higher computational complexity)